# Simplifying obj model baking

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to bake multiple obj models but I have to copy and paste a long code to bake one model. This is making my main mod class really long.

I tried creating classes and making new objects but it doesn't seem to work because the `onModelBakeEvent` is supposed to be static.

```
@SubscribeEvent
public static void onModelBakeEvent(ModelBakeEvent event) {
    try {
        IUnbakedModel model = getModelOrLogError(new ResourceLocation("unixmod:block/fabricator.obj"), "Missing fabricator model");
        if (model instanceof OBJModel) {
            IBakedModel bakedModel = model.bake(event.getModelLoader(), ModelLoader.defaultTextureGetter(),
                    new BasicState(model.getDefaultState(), true), DefaultVertexFormats.POSITION_TEX_COLOR_NORMAL);

            IBakedModel bakedInvModel = model.bake(event.getModelLoader(), ModelLoader.defaultTextureGetter(),
                    new BasicState(model.getDefaultState(), true), DefaultVertexFormats.ITEM);

            bakedInvModel = new PerspectiveMapWrapper(bakedInvModel, BLOCK_TRANSFORMS);


            event.getModelRegistry().put(new ModelResourceLocation("unixmod:fabricator", ""), bakedModel);
            event.getModelRegistry().put(new ModelResourceLocation("unixmod:fabricator", "inventory"), bakedInvModel);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        IUnbakedModel model = getModelOrLogError(new ResourceLocation("unixmod:block/acidmushroom.obj"), "Missing acidmushroom model");
        if (model instanceof OBJModel) {
            IBakedModel bakedModel = model.bake(event.getModelLoader(), ModelLoader.defaultTextureGetter(),
                    new BasicState(model.getDefaultState(), true), DefaultVertexFormats.POSITION_TEX_COLOR_NORMAL);

            IBakedModel bakedInvModel = model.bake(event.getModelLoader(), ModelLoader.defaultTextureGetter(),
                    new BasicState(model.getDefaultState(), true), DefaultVertexFormats.ITEM);

            bakedInvModel = new PerspectiveMapWrapper(bakedInvModel, BLOCK_TRANSFORMS);


            event.getModelRegistry().put(new ModelResourceLocation("unixmod:acidmushroom", ""), bakedModel);
            event.getModelRegistry().put(new ModelResourceLocation("unixmod:acidmushroom", "inventory"), bakedInvModel);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work because the onModelBakeEvent is supposed to be static. And sorry I accidentally flagged you. I thought it was supposed to quote you and I pressed it. -_-

Comment: That's no problem, SO takes some time to get used to after all. If you have good information then please edit it into your question so it is immediately obvious for new readers. Other note: make your question *really* clear, I suppose you are asking if there are ways to simplify the baking?

Comment: Instead of a static event handling, you can do something like `MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(yourInstance)`. The repetitive code can be placed in one or few methods; the exception handling is not optimal.